# Sending a workflow email to a fax number formatted like an email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that will email to a specified customer using another list to look up the email address.  This works well.  However, when I plug in a fax number formatted like an email (5552349876@faxmaker.com) it shows completed successfully, but the fax never gets delivered to my inbox.

I've tested sending a fax from my email and it works, not sure why it doesn't deliver in the workflow.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I should have added that I am using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise on a 2008R2 server, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.  It wasn't a SharePoint issue but a permissions issue from the SharePoint default "from" email address to the fax server account.